# Why is \scshape not changing in XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex

I'm trying to alter `\scshape` in XeLaTeX, but for some reason, three reasonable attempts (xpatch, \def, and \renewcommand) seem to have no effect whatsoever (only in XeLaTeX).  A nonworking example is below (note that the 5 em space is just to make it clear when the redefinition is working, and obviously not intended for use in a real document):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\scshape}
  {\spaceskip=5em}
  {}{}
%\let\myscshape\scshape
%\def\scshape{\spaceskip=5em\myscshape}
%\renewcommand{\scshape}{\myscshape\spaceskip=5em}



\begin{document}
\noindent\textsc{Test thing test}\\
\scshape Test thing test\\
\scshape\spaceskip=5em Test thing test
\end{document}
```

Comment: The given code doesn't change anything in lualatex either. `\scshape` might be protected. If you append to a hook (parameterless macro), `\appto{\xscshape}{\spaceskip=5em >>\color{red}}`, it works; if you append to an unprotected macro, `\newcommand\xscshape{\scshape}\xapptocmd{\xscshape}  {\spaceskip=5em >>\color{red}}  {}{}`, it also works. The prepends also work. If you pre/append to a command (=parametered macro, like `\textsc`), the replacement text is per/appended to as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the patch at begin document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\xapptocmd{\scshape}
  {\spaceskip=5em}
  {}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Test thing test}

\scshape Test thing test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant—many thanks!

Comment: Out of intellectual curiousity, why does using \AtBeginDocument make it work?

Comment: @ezgranet A great part of font setup is done at begin document; different font packages may have different ideas about how to realize small caps.

Comment: thank you—very interesting.